# Redhat container for LXD

Tags: lxd

I've seen on the Ubuntu website that redhat is a supported guest on LXD.

However it does not seem to be part of the default image list on a default install of LXD.

Is there a way to have Redhat on LXD in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

well, Not redhat per-se, but Centos, yes.

You can see all the [images at the linuxcontainers.org site](https://us.images.linuxcontainers.org/).

And, here is an example on my ubuntu 16.04 machine:

```
dpb@helo:~[]$ lxc image list images: |grep -i centos
| centos/6/amd64 (1 more)         | ac4253d28519 | yes    | Centos 6 (amd64) (20170818_02:16)          | x86_64  | 66.21MB  | Aug 18, 2017 at 2:31am (UTC)  |
| centos/6/i386 (1 more)          | 5619584e8da1 | yes    | Centos 6 (i386) (20170818_02:16)           | i686    | 66.15MB  | Aug 18, 2017 at 2:32am (UTC)  |
| centos/7/amd64 (1 more)         | dafefb5f0a63 | yes    | Centos 7 (amd64) (20170818_02:16)          | x86_64  | 65.27MB  | Aug 18, 2017 at 2:33am (UTC)  |
|                                 | 293e05de21c1 | yes    | Centos 6 (amd64) (20170817_02:16)          | x86_64  | 66.25MB  | Aug 17, 2017 at 2:31am (UTC)  |
|                                 | 36c0db7cee4d | yes    | Centos 6 (i386) (20170817_02:16)           | i686    | 66.13MB  | Aug 17, 2017 at 2:32am (UTC)  |
|                                 | 999e1d3d5a52 | yes    | Centos 7 (amd64) (20170816_02:16)          | x86_64  | 65.27MB  | Aug 16, 2017 at 2:33am (UTC)  |
|                                 | a22d66494d46 | yes    | Centos 7 (amd64) (20170817_02:16)          | x86_64  | 65.29MB  | Aug 17, 2017 at 2:33am (UTC)  |
|                                 | f71860cca3e8 | yes    | Centos 6 (amd64) (20170816_02:16)          | x86_64  | 66.22MB  | Aug 16, 2017 at 2:31am (UTC)  |
|                                 | f884baaed792 | yes    | Centos 6 (i386) (20170816_02:16)           | i686    | 66.15MB  | Aug 16, 2017 at 2:32am (UTC)  |
dpb@helo:~[]$ lxc launch images:centos/7/amd64 centos-7
Creating centos-7
Starting centos-7
dpb@helo:~[]$ lxc exec centos-7 -- cat /etc/os-release /etc/centos-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```